# structure of the once in a blue moon

Tags: sentence-structure

Which one is correct from the structural point of view? Why?:

> Only once in a blue moon will Mr. Smith let us get out of class early.

or

> Only once in a blue moon, Mr. Smith will let us get out of class
>   early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both are correct.**

> Only once in a blue moon will Mr. Smith let us get out of class early.

Inversion is used correctly, **will** is moved to the front of the subject **Mr. Smith**

> Only once in a blue moon, Mr. Smith will let us get out of class early.

Original form of the first sentence, of course this is correct!

As per OP's comment about the usage of inversion of auxiliary verbs, this may help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469178/english-subject-auxiliary-inversion/475907#475907

and this: [Neither nor inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165781/neither-nor-inversion/166102#166102)
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you @Omega Krypton. But when we can move auxiliary verbs to the front of the subjects?

Comment: please check the new link, this may help you ;)

Comment: Thank you. After I considered your guidance and watched this link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQfzZRSTSc), I got it.

Comment: welcome. hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The key to the answer is the inversion. You can watch more useful explanations here:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K0npnSYjJE
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQfzZRSTSc